# Storing plots as variables in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, facet

Hello Stack community,

For my project, I am visualizing impulse response function plots in R. I am trying to store each plot as an object in R (see PART1 of the code) in order to later append all of them in one plot (using cowplot library), as a facet chart (see PART 2 of the code). However, ultimate result of the code is an empty chart with only titles at the top.

[image]
I believe reason for empty plot should be that R stores my plots as empty objects

[image]

I would greatly appreciate your help.

R code below:

```
#PART 1: Making IRF plots and storing them as objects

plot.1 <- plot(irf(df, impulse = "abc", response = "abc", n.ahead = 8, ortho = TRUE, runs = 1000, seed = 1))
plot.2 <- plot(irf(df, impulse = "abc", response = "def", n.ahead = 8, ortho = TRUE, runs = 1000, seed = 1))
plot.3 <- plot(irf(df, impulse = "abc", response = "ghi", n.ahead = 8, ortho = TRUE, runs = 1000, seed = 1))
plot.4 <- plot(irf(df, impulse = "abc", response = "jkl", n.ahead = 8, ortho = TRUE, runs = 1000, seed = 1))

#PART 2: making facet

library(cowplot)
plot_grid(plot.1, plot.2, plot.3, plot.4, rremove("x.text"), 
          labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
          ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1) recordPlot** Use `recordPlot` to record each plot.

```
library(cowplot)
library(irtoys)

plot(irf(Scored2pl, items=c(2,3,7)), co=NA, ask = FALSE); plot1 <- recordPlot()
plot(irf(Scored2pl), co="red", label=TRUE, ask = FALSE); plot2 <- recordPlot()
plot(irf(Scored2pl), co="blue", label=TRUE, ask = FALSE); plot3 <- recordPlot()
plot(irf(Scored2pl), co="green", label=TRUE, ask = FALSE); plot4 <- recordPlot()

plot_grid(plot1, plot2, plot3, plot4, labels = LETTERS)
```

[image: screenshot]

**2) formula** cowplot also accepts a formula. The output is the same as above.

```
library(cowplot)
library(irtoys)

plot1 <- ~ plot(irf(Scored2pl, items=c(2,3,7)), co=NA)
plot2 <- ~ plot(irf(Scored2pl), co="red", label=TRUE)
plot3 <- ~ plot(irf(Scored2pl), co="blue", label=TRUE)
plot4 <- ~ plot(irf(Scored2pl), co="green", label=TRUE)

plot_grid(plot1, plot2, plot3, plot4, labels = LETTERS)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly store plots this way in R. Unlike most other functions in R, the `plot` generic draws the plot as a *side effect*, and typically does not return an object that can be used to recreate the plot again (as would be required for the objects `plot.1`, `plot.2` etc) to do what you want them to do here.

To get them to work in `cowplot`, you need to wrap the plot calls in a *function* that will draw the plot, and pass these to `cowplot::ggdraw`.

Of course, I don't have your data, so will show here a simple example using base R plots

```r
library(gridGraphics)
library(cowplot)

plot1 <- ggdraw(function() plot(x = 1:10, y = 1:10))
plot2 <- ggdraw(function() plot(x = 1:10, y = 10:1))
plot3 <- ggdraw(function() plot(x = 1:10, y = c(1:5, 5:1)))
plot4 <- ggdraw(function() plot(x = 1:10, y = c(10:6, 6:10)))

plot_grid(plot1, plot2, plot3, plot4, labels = LETTERS[1:4])
```

[image]